# Route being called before the state has been set to be passed as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

As I am navigating to the Wallet Page, I am trying to check if the user has logged in before and if he has, pass the user id that has been stored in the localstorage into the WalletPage component as a prop.

However, the prop is being sent over as a **null** value because the user id state is being sent over before it is done setting.

Is there an issue with how I am trying to pass the user ID over as a prop? How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

**App Component**
**Setting of states**

```
 useEffect(()=>{
      console.log("Upon entering app.js, check if loginStatus is defined in localStorage and follow it's value")
      console.log(localStorage);
      let localStorageLoginStatus = localStorage.getItem('loginStatus');
      let localStorageLoggedInUserName = localStorage.getItem('loggedInUserName');
      let localStorageloggedInUserID = localStorage.getItem('loggedInUserID');
      if(localStorageLoginStatus && localStorageLoggedInUserName){
        setLoginStatus(true);
        setLoggedInUserName(localStorageLoggedInUserName);
        setLoggedInUserID(localStorageloggedInUserID);
      }
    },[])
```

**Routing code**

```
   <Router>
        <>
          {loginStatus && <NavbarTemplate loggedInUserName={loggedInUserName}></NavbarTemplate>}
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<LandingPage></LandingPage>}></Route>
            <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage loginFunction={loginFunction} registerUserAccountFunction={registerAccountFunction} currentState='login'></LoginPage>}></Route>
            <Route path='/register' element={<LoginPage loginFunction={loginFunction} registerUserAccountFunction={registerAccountFunction} currentState='signup'></LoginPage>}></Route>
            <Route path='/currency' element={<CurrencyPage></CurrencyPage>}></Route>
            <Route path='/wallet' element={<WalletPage loggedInUserID={loggedInUserID}> </WalletPage>}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </>
      </Router>
```

**WalletPage Component**

```
   useEffect(()=>{    
        console.log("PROPS");
        console.log(props.loggedInUserID);
        //Set user id
        setLoggedInUserID(props.loggedInUserID);
        getAllWalletIDBelongingToUser(props.loggedInUserID);
    },[])
```

Comment: in the app component you can try showing the routes only setting the logged in user id, i.e after auth
or try using a useMemo in App to set logged in user id

Comment: @Azzy i can set the route to only be available if loginStatus is true as you mentioned, but there will be a warning in the console log alerting me that a undefined route is being accessed. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: why even pass the `loggedInUserID`? you could also directly use the local storage in the `WalletPage` or even better create a custom hook or context in which this state is managed. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/avoid-prop-drilling-with-react-context-api/#:~:text=Prop%20drilling%20is%20a%20situation,where%20the%20data%20is%20needed.

Comment: So I guess this is not the normal auth flow, when there will be silent login and then redirect to the page,
if you are using local storage, I think you can read the user info before the app is loaded  and pass the params to the top level app

Comment: @Xiduzo is it better to just read from the local storage in WalletPage ?  I thought the better process is to pass the information down as a prop.

Comment: yes, but preferably you would like to use something like react context to prevent prop drilling while still being able to access these values in multiple component. Check the link I send before and https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html for the official docs